# Cartoon about a group which visits different races trying to find one with a perfect soul (which later forms some kind of pyramid)

Tags: story-identification

there was this (french?) cartoon where someone/a group has to visit various strange fantasy races and tries to find the one person with a special soul. When he finds them that souls "beams out" and some kind of pyramid of light forms with the souls of other races. I know this is vague but it was 20 years ago, can someone help out?

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that you've not remembered any additional details [in the 2 years since you first asked this](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/2p78u1/tomtcartoon_8090s_cartoon_where_someone_visits/)

Comment: This might help [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question). For example, what was the style of the cartoon (stylised, realistic, faux-anime)? Who were the group? Were they adults or children? Did you watch it in English? Was it a serious adult cartoon or something for kids? What did the other races look like? Why were they looking for this special soul? Did they actually use the phrases "perfect soul" and "beam out"?

Comment: No idea if it's a match, but the French/Japanese cartoon series "Ulysses 31" comes up in questions around here every so often. Could that be it?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omer_and_the_Starchild